# using fpdf to write html content to pdf

Tags: php

I am trying to use fpdf and html2pdf to write contents of a div to a pdf file. But the WriteHTML function doesn't seem to work.  What's wrong with the code?

It says

> call to undefined function WriteHTML() in demo.php on line 43

Below is my code.

```
<?php

$contents = $_POST['divContent'];


require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php') ;
require('html2pdf/html2pdf.php');

class PDF extends PDF_HTML
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
    // Logo
    $this->Image('fpdf/logo.png',10,6,30);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Title
    $this->Cell(60,10,'Report',1,0,'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}

// Instanciation of inherited class
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
$pdf->MultiCell(190,10,WriteHTML($contents));
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember your `PDF` extends the main class`(PDF_HTML)`, so upon calling the class `PDF`, 
It will inherit all functions contained in `PDF_HTML`, hence you must also access it properly

```
   $pdf->MultiCell(190,10,$pdf->WriteHTML($contents));//you were not accessing the function properly
```

Comment: pleasure @vinayr

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
 $pdf->WriteHTML($contents);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
This code is used to generate PDF BY HTML Code.


<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$row=file('toys.txt');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);  
foreach($row as $rowValue) {
    $data=explode(';',$rowValue);
    foreach($data as $columnValue)
        $pdf->Cell(90,12,$columnValue,1);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);       
        $pdf->Ln();
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: absolutly not thematical